# Excel: how to stop numbers being converted to text strings n saving as .csv?

Tags: excel, export-to-csv

I am saving out some data as a .csv file from Excel. However numerical data is being saved as a text string, i.e the number is "quoted" in the resulting file. How do I prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are your Excel columns defined? If they are defined as text, than this is what you get. Define/format your columns as numeric if you want them to be numeric.